# How to order search results based on author field content

Tags: 8, views, users, search

I am using Drupal 8 search views, I would like to order the search result so that the content that's author has field "X" filled out should be ordered first and all other content where the author has field "X" empty shows up after. How can I achieve this with views

I made a relationship between the content and the author. I can access field "x" in the fields part of views, but it does not show up in the "filter" or "order by" parts.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost have done it.

> I made a relationship between the content and the author. I can access field "x" in the fields part of views, but it does not show up in the "filter" or "order by" parts.

add that fix "X" in sort section and sort it as **Descending**. when you make it descending contents with null values appear after those that have value.

Comment: I think this is unlikely to have the expected result. If field x is in the first sort criteria, it'll sort items by the value in that field, the side effect being that results with field x empty will appear last. If field x isn't the first sort criteria, it'll only be considered after all previous sorts are considered, and only having an impact when the previous sorts all result in a tie.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I mentioned, the field didnt show up in the "order by/sort" section. I found the solution. I had to add the field to the index in the search index settings at /admin/config/search/search-api/index/course_search/fields

Answer (score 0):

The field needs to be added to the search index here:

```
/admin/config/search/search-api/index/YOUR_SEARCH_INDEX_NAME/fields
```

Then the field shows up in the sort and filter sections in views.